# postgresql query with join and limit

Tags: postgresql

I have a table Gift. Gift's can have many gift_images via a table association. I am trying to return a LIMITED # gifts with a certain privacy level that have at least one gift_images association.

In essence, I want to return the: gift entry with its FIRST associated gift_image (gift_image should be sorted by a position value it has, with position 1 being the FIRST). Gifts without a gift_image associated should be ignored.

This is what I have, but it's definitely not working.

```
SELECT gifts.* FROM gifts LEFT JOIN gift_images ON gifts.id = gift_images.gift_id WHERE gifts.privacy = 2 ORDER BY gift_images.position ASC LIMIT 10
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to ignore gifts without images, you should use an `INNER JOIN` instead of the `LEFT JOIN`. In addition, for the query to be meaningful, you should select some field from gift_images in addition to fields from gift.

If all gifts that have gift images have an image for which position = 1, this query should do:

```
SELECT gifts.*, gift_images.*
FROM gifts
INNER JOIN gift_images
ON gifts.id = gift_images.gift_id
WHERE gifts.privacy = 2
AND gift_images.position = 1
LIMIT 10
```

Otherwise, you could try

```
SELECT gifts.*, gift_images.*
FROM gifts
INNER JOIN (SELECT gift_id, MIN(position) AS min_position
            FROM gift_images
            GROUP BY gift_id) AS positions
ON positions.gift_id = gifts.id
INNER JOIN gift_images
ON gift_images.gift_id = gifts.id
AND gift_images.position = positions.min_position
```